# Is there a way to check if two string with same value are the same instance in C#?

Tags: c#, string, equality

String in C# is a reference type, but it has overridden `==`, and `Equals()` to compare the value of strings. Is there a way to check if two strings are indeed the same instance and point to the same memory?

Even `Object.ReferenceEquals("A", "A")` will return true since it just calls `==`.

This test will pass. So still waiting to check if the same instance.

```
  [Test]
        public void TestString()
        {
            var a = "A";
            var b = "A";
            var c = a;
            Assert.IsTrue((object)a == (object)b);
            Assert.IsTrue(ReferenceEquals(a,b));  //It is same as objA == objB
            Assert.IsTrue(Object.ReferenceEquals(a,b));

            Assert.AreEqual(a,b);
            Assert.AreSame(a, b);

            unsafe
            {
                TypedReference tra = __makeref(a);
                IntPtr ptra = (IntPtr)(&tra);


                TypedReference trb = __makeref(b);
                IntPtr ptrb = (IntPtr)(&trb);

                Assert.AreNotEqual(ptra, ptrb);
                Assert.AreNotSame(ptra, ptrb);


                TypedReference trc = __makeref(c);
                IntPtr ptrc = (IntPtr)(&trc);

                Assert.AreNotEqual(ptra, ptrc); 
                Assert.AreNotSame(ptra, ptrc);

                Assert.IsFalse(ptra == ptrc);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: They might *be* the same reference, I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler optimizes two identical immutable values into one.  Why do you need to differentiate them?  What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: [String interning](https://duongnt.com/string-interning/) - string literals that are equivalent are replaced by references to the same literal.

Comment: "Object.ReferenceEquals("A", "A") will return true, since it just calls ==" - no, it does not

Comment: Try`Object.ReferenceEquals("A", "AB".Substring(1))`

Answer (score 9):

Your test passes because string literals are automatically interned, meaning they share the same memory. Because they share the same memory, every form of equality is going to return `true`: `ReferenceEquals`, `Equals`, pinning and comparison through a pointer, and `==`.

Now, non-literals are not interned, which would make your test fails for `ReferenceEquals`. For example, for

```
var a = Console.ReadLine(); // assume user enters cat
var b = Console.ReadLine(); // assume user enters cat
```

`ReferenceEquals` will return `false`. But if you change the code to

```
var a = string.Intern(Console.ReadLine()); // assume user enters cat
var b = string.Intern(Console.ReadLine()); // assume user enters cat
```

you're right back to having `ReferenceEquals` returning `true` again.

In short, there is most definitely a way to check whether two strings are the same reference using `ReferenceEquals` or via pointer.

Incidentally, if you interned one of the inputs, that does not imply the other input is also interned, unless you call `Intern` on both. Interning explicitly is useful for reducing memory when you're likely to work with many strings that are likely to be the same value based on reading console/file input, reading from a database, or otherwise calculating.

Also, [string.IsInterned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isinterned?view=net-7.0) can be useful in some limited scenarios, e.g. maybe for detecting if a string is not interned for some reason when you expected it to be.

Finally, here are a couple of interesting illustrations. Consider

```
var c = "cat";
var d = new string("cat");
var e = c;
```

and then these assertions,

```
Assert.IsTrue(ReferenceEquals(c,d)); // fails, c is interned, d is not
Assert.IsTrue(ReferenceEquals(c,e)); // succeeds, both c and e reference interned "cat"
```